# In real world ASP.NET website developments, do developers normally use the set of login controls provided by VS, or develop their own controls?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

The reason I'm asking this is I suspect the set of login controls are cumbersome to use/tweak. For example, I'd imagine it'd be hard to tell the user their password is not correct.

Comment: Why would you want to tell the user something specific like their password is incorrect? In doing so you're confirming that the user name is real, which means any attacker has now found a valid username and can concentrate on trying passwords.

Comment: @blowdart: that was just an example and it misses the point of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried using them, and after a while I was ultimately left with just the login control itself. All the logic to authenticate, and manage users was written from scratch.  I just didn't want to use the default MembershipProvider that comes with VS.

You can customize the look at feel via CSS, and I believe there's an Authenticate event on the control that you can hook into, to perform your authentication.

If you want your login section to be very different from the standard look and feel, you might want to consider rolling your own.  The worst place to end up is to work around the control and not with it.

Answer (score 4):

No, I never use the built-in ones. But I love starting from scratch in any case, so that might just be me :-)

I always create classes for `User`, `UserPermission`, `UserNotFoundException`, `UnauthorizedException`, etc. and implement real OOP that just feels right. MVC but not the MVC template.

Answer (score 4):

I use the built in controls. They provide a good amount of configurability and the safety needed for professional development. There are very few points - besides the learning experience - in writing your own.

> For example, I'd imagine it'd be hard to tell the user their password is not correct.

It sure can be done very easily. The FailureAction / FailureText / FailureStyle properties are your friends.

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel..
I use build in controls provided by asp.net,
for any custom functionality I just inherit the builtin controls.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I use the OOB Login Controls (coupled with some style) and spend my time on the actual substance of the application.  Similarly, I don't invent my own logger every time create an application.